# Suggestions for real-time charting with SignalR in C# application

Tags: web-services, charts, signalr, real-time

I am building a dashboard that will monitor production data, and am able to access this data via web services. The data changes every 1 minute, so I would like to have a page with 4 charts/gauges (the number of systems I am monitoring) that would get the data pushed to them with a successive web service call.

Can anyone suggest a good charting kit that would work well with C#? And would SignalR be a good fit here do you think? I have read that node.js and socket.io are options, but I have no experience with node yet. I would like something along the lines of DevExpress.  Perhaps jquery and something on the front end works here as well? Thanks!

Comment: SignalR seems like a perfect fit - you can push changes from the server to the client when the server gets new data. There are C# and javascript SignalR clients. Here you can find some tutorials that should help you get started:http://www.asp.net/signalr. Also take a look at the stock ticker sample (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr) which seems to be similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

For such a dashboard SignalR is definitely a good fit if you already work with .NET and ASP.NET. For a *web* dashboard in particular, a good graphic library is [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which is open source and pure JavaScript. It's simple and straight to the point, but often *less is more*. You can build interesting kinds of charts with it.

[This project](http://elmahr.apphb.com/) is maybe interesting for you as a sample of those 2 technologies together. If you press the *skulls* to raise errors, they will be triggered on a backend simulator and pushed to the dashboard using SignalR. You will notice a piechart graph there, which is done using Raphael and updates live when new errors are received.

The code of the project is [here](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/wiki/Home), it's a bit complex but maybe you want to have a look anyway. It's based on SignalR 1.x, but overall concepts are still the same.